# Why Javascript innerHTML add quote automatically to my string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, innerhtml

I am trying to add some HTML code and text in a `div`. If I add just a text there isn't any problem. But if I add some text with HTML code, it automatically adds quotes to my text.

```html
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function test() {
            document.getElementById("viewer1").innerHTML = "text";// this is not add any quote to text
            document.getElementById("viewer2").innerHTML = "text <b>Bold Text</b>"; //this is add quote to text but not add quote to <b>Bold Text</b>

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="viewer1"></div>
<div id="viewer2"></div>
<button onclick="test()">Test it</button>

</body>
</html>
```

It looks like this

> ```
>  viewer1 content = text
>  viever2 content ="text" <b>Bold Text</b>
> ```

I don't want the quotes. How can it be removed?

Take a look at the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: That’s how the Chrome inspector formats text nodes. Why do you care what it looks like in the inspector?

Comment: Quotes are **just** representation of text node

Comment: @Ryan If i'm not wrong, this has nothing to do with `space`

Comment: @A.Wolff: Ah, you’re right, Chrome just puts quotes around every text node.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.
its importand because i use it for store data. 
But if its not changed it. its will not problem . 
i thought its changed my data.

Comment: This is why you should ask about your *real* problem, not [what you think causes it](http://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quotes will not shown in web page. it's just for chrome console node.

Comment: i am trying to do syntax highlighter , and javascript  throw error . i was looked to dom and i saw this.
i thought its its was changed to  data .. 
if just chrome show it with quote its not problem.. 
Thank you